# saving form-elements in an array using mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean

i am trying to develop a MEAN app, i am able to send data from front end to back end server, i am able to push **array** of data in mongoose schema, but i am not able to push the **Object elements** inside the array one by one. my server code looks like

```
 router.post('/', function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.body.details);//getting data in array
     console.log(req.body.academics);//getting data in array
     console.log(req.body.trainings);////getting data in *object*
     var detail = req.body.details;
     console.log(detail.city); // i can get data here 
     var register = new recruit(req.body);

register.contact.push({
    city: detail.city || "",//but the data doesnot get inserted now
    state: detail.state || "",
    municipalityVdc: detail.municipalityVdc || "",
    wardNo: detail.wardNo || "",
    houseNo: detail.houseNo || "",
    streetName: detail.streetName || "",
    contactNo: detail.contactNo || "",
    eContactNo: detail.eContactNo || "",
    email: detail.email || "",
    aEmail: detail.aEmail || "",
    facebookId: detail.facebookId || "",
    linkedinId: detail.linkedinId || ""
});
register.qualification.push(req.body.academics);// array of data are inserted inside the mongoose schema
register.trainings.push(req.body.trainings);// data get inserted
```

it is fine saving all data at once but i am trying to manage data in different array. i have got another array too where details are to be inserted

```
  register.basicDetails.push({
    firstName: detail.firstName || "",//no data are inserted here too
    lastName: detail.lastName || "",
    fathersName: detail.fathersName || "",
    dob: detail.dob || "",
    marritalStatus: detail.marritalStatus || "",
    drivingLicense: detail.drivingLicense || "",
    vehicle: detail.vehicle || "",
    gender: detail.gender || "",
    photo: req.file.originalname || "",
    jobTitle: detail.jobTitle || "",
    experiance: detail.experiance || ""
});
register.save(function(err, respond) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        res.json(respond);
    }
})
```

});
module.exports = router;

my code works if i make object of mongoose module and directly save it to database but only **array** are inserted not **objects**,
my working code looks like

```
 router.post('/', function(req, res) {

var register = new recruit(req.body);

register.save(function(err, respond) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        res.json(respond);
    }
   })
 });
 module.exports = router;
```

some one please enlighten me about managing  data using mongoose, and correct me where i am wrong. will highly appreciate any response.

Answer (score 0):

i think help to you

your getting Client side data object is same to your mongoose recruit schema field ,then only it will save all data

for example

this is user scheme

```
var UserSchema= new mongoose.Schema({

name:{type:String},
dateCreated:{type:String},
place:[{
    city:{type:String},
    state:{type:String}
}]
```

});

this is client side data (req.body)

```
{ "name":"test","dateCreated":"date","place":[{"city":"chennai","state":"tamil"}]}
```

save function

```
var newUser = new  User(data)
newUser.save(function(err, respond) {
if (err) {
    throw err;
} else {
    res.json(respond);
}})});
```

output

```
{ place:
    [ { _id: 5737548a96d6deb40b321a53,
        state: 'tamil',
        city: 'chennai' } ],
    _id: 5737548a96d6deb40b321a52,
    dateCreated: 'date' }
```

Comment: i no this way, actually i have object inside my (req.body) along with arrays too. and want to push into new array inside mongoose schema like:
newUser.details.push({name:req.body.name}). where detais is defined inside the schema. in single object like your example its fine but i have object inside req.body. any help?

Comment: hi pls give clear example , becoz in your example  (req.body.details) is array  and how u get values in array like this (details.city,details.state) ,object only using this way. so u can't get value from details like this (details.city)

Comment: (req.body) is also object . you try to save value like this (var register = new recruit(req.body);) .. so array of client data ill set to array of schema field and object of client data ill set to object of schema field.. but object of client data ill not set in array of schema field

Comment: what i am getting in req.body is :{ academics:
   [ { level: 'bachelordsaf',
       university: 'Purbanchsdafal University',
       grade: '2.8fsda' },
     { level: 'sdfas', university: 'dfsad', grade
  trainings:
   [ { title: 'Php/MysQlsdfasd',
       duration: '3monthsfsadf',
       objective: 'to build dynasdafmic websites'
  details:
   { firstName: 'kishor',
     lastName: 'giri',
     fathersName: 'hari sharan giri',
     dob: '1993-03-28T18:15:00.000Z',
     jobTitle: 'Laravel Developer',
     experiance: 'One year',
     marritalStatus: 'single',
  } }

Comment: so there exist new object (details) inside req.body object.